# python Use Pool to create multiple processes but not execute the results

Tags: multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

**I put all the functions are placed in a class**, including the creation of the process of the function and the implementation of the function, in another file to call the function of this class

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def initData(self, type):
# create six process to deal with the data
    if type == 'train':
        data = pd.read_csv('./data/train_merged_8.csv')
    elif type == 'test':
        data = pd.read_csv('./data/test_merged_2.csv')
    modelvec = allWord2Vec('no').getModel()
    modelvec_all = allWord2Vec('all').getModel()
    modelvec_stop = allWord2Vec('stop').getModel()
    p = Pool(6)
    count = 0
    for i in data.index:
        count += 1
        p.apply_async(self.valueCal, args=(i, data, modelvec, modelvec_all, modelvec_stop))
        if count % 1000 == 0:
            print(str(count // 100) + 'h rows of data has been dealed')
    p.close()
    p.join


def valueCal(self, i, data, modelvec, modelvec_all, modelvec_stop):
# the function run in process
    list_con = []
    q1 = str(data.get_value(i, 'question1')).split()
    q2 = str(data.get_value(i, 'question2')).split()
    f1 = self.getF1_union(q1, q2)
    f2 = self.getF2_inter(q1, q2)
    f3 = self.getF3_sum(q1, q2)
    f4_q1 = len(q1)
    f4_q2 = len(q2)
    f4_rate = f4_q1/f4_q2            

    q1 = [','.join(str(ve)) for ve in q1]
    q2 = [','.join(str(ve)) for ve in q2]
    list_con.append('|'.join(q1))
    list_con.append('|'.join(q2))

    list_con.append(f1)
    list_con.append(f2)
    list_con.append(f3)
    list_con.append(f4_q1)
    list_con.append(f4_q2)
    list_con.append(f4_rate)

    f = open('./data/test.txt', 'a')
    f.write('\t'.join(list_con) + '\n')
    f.close()
```

The result appears very soon like this, but I have not even seen the file being created.But when I check the task manager, there are indeed six processes are created and consumed a lot of resources I cpu. And when the program is finished, the file is still not created.
How can i solve this problem?

```
10h rows of data have been dealed
20h rows of data have been dealed
30h rows of data have been dealed
40h rows of data have been dealed
```

Comment: Have you tested your function without using multiprocessing first ?

Comment: Yes, I have tested my function is no problem can call and have the correct return, but still no response @Himal

Comment: You should use a [`multiprocessing.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock) when writing to the `./data/test.txt` file. something similar to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes)

Comment: Thank you , I will do it @Himal